# regex creation with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

i need a regex that fits these conditions

- may contain letters and numbers. numbers are optional but must contain at least 1 letter
- at least 2 characters
- can contain ONLY the "-" character of special characters. this is optional
- must begin with a letter
- no whitespace
- no turkish characters

How should i create a regex query according to these conditions?

Comment: show what you've tried

Comment: I've never worked with regex before. I tried to create a little bit but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function like so:

```js
function isGood(string){
  return /^[a-z][a-z0-9-]+$/i.test(string);
}
console.log(isGood('This should return false'))
console.log(isGood('@no'));
console.log(isGood('Nice'));
console.log(isGood('a'));
console.log(isGood('a!'));
console.log(isGood('great'));
console.log(isGood('This-should-also-pass-the-test'));
```